# Package manager has died Cause by DeadObjectException when i use "getPackageInfo" method

Tags: android, package-managers

Exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died 
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:139)
at com.crypt.lord.e.a.f(AppHelper.java:375)
at com.crypt.lord.a.f.a(InstallListData.java:56)
at com.crypt.lord.a.f.a(InstallListData.java:34)
at com.crypt.lord.a.f.c(InstallListData.java:90)
at com.crypt.lord.impl.CryptLordServiceImpl$5.run(CryptLordServiceImpl.java:429)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small 
parcel; remote process probably died
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInfo(IPackageManager.ja
va:2187)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:134)
... 6 more
```

my code

```
    public int isSystemApp(String packageName) {
    int systemApp = 1;
    int notSystemApp = 2;
    int unKnown = 3;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(packageName)) {
        return unKnown;
    }
    if (mContext == null) {
        return unKnown;
    }
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager != null && packageName != null) {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
            if (packageInfo != null && packageInfo.applicationInfo != null && ((packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0)) {
                return systemApp;
            } else {
                return notSystemApp;
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return unKnown;
}
```

i found some other questions "package manager has died",casued by TransactionTooLargeException,the answer is 1MB limit on a Binder transaction.but i have not found the reason "package manager has died cause By DeadObjectException",is PackageManagerServeice died? how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was?

Comment: @DanBreslau no,i have not

Comment: @DanBreslau, two years later, did you find out what was causing it?

Comment: @Keselme I'm not the OP, of course. For myself, I don't have access anymore to the code where I saw a similar issue, so I likely never will know.

Comment: I have the same issue. But only on Android 6